# Can Warforged be repaired with a skill check?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, pathfinder-1e, healing, eberron, warforged

We're running a Pathfinder game, set in Eberron. In our first session, our Warforged was brought to very negative health and is thus disabled. She won't heal naturally, only receives half of magical healing, and nobody knows the repair spell. Seemingly our only option would be to drag her back to the village and spend several days having out healers casting/resting or leave her behind. We do have an artificer, but he doesn't have anything that can help.

It seems to me like he should be able to make some kind of skill check to physically repair the Warforged but I can't find anything relevant in the rulebooks. Is there any official precedent I can bring to our GM? Or if not what other options might be available for a level 1 party to get our Warforged back in working order?

Note: I'm sure we can talk to the GM and work something out, but I'm looking for something official I can take to him.

Comment: Uhhh, how does your Artificer not have Repair Light Damage on the infusion list?

Comment: @Ernir I'm not sure. I thought he would have something (I haven't read the Artificer rules) but he said all he can do is craft gadgets. Are you implying that he should have it in that it was a serious oversight to not take it, or it's something that he probably has but just doesn't realize it?

Comment: The second. Artificers know their entire Infusion list, I can't think of a way for the character not to have it.

Comment: @Ernir Great, thank you! I will bring it up with the artificer. Every bit helps. There's a lot of HP to heal!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sure. The core Eberron rulebook has the following:

> ### Craft
>
> **Repair Warforged:** A character with ranks in certain Craft
>   skills can attempt to repair a warforged character who has taken
>   damage. A check requires 8 hours and restores a number of hit points
>   equal to the Craft check result –15. A character can take 10 on this
>   check but can't take 20. Other constructs can't be repaired in this
>   way (...)
>
> Applicable Craft skills include armorsmithing,
>   blacksmithing, gemcutting, and sculpting. A warforged with an
>   applicable Craft skill can repair itself.

– **Eberron** Campaign Setting, Craft, p.46

So, if someone in your party has any of those skills, you're good to go. (I don't think your using the Pathfinder system instead of 3.5 would or should make any difference, but be sure to check with your DM, of course.)

Comment: Great, thank you so much! That'll help a lot, assuming we can convince our artificer to work in the snow for 8 hours!

Comment: @DrewS Glad I could help. I'm pretty sure you'll find a way. :)