# How can we compensate for a Warforged's lack of healing?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, pathfinder-1e, healing, eberron, warforged

Our Pathfinder in Eberron group has a Warforged barbarian. As such, she has the most health, takes the most damage, and is the hardest to heal (No natural healing, half healing from spells). This presents a problem, both in keeping her up in combat and healing her between combats.

What we've got so far:

- The [craft skill](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/44636/can-warforged-be-repaired-with-a-skill-check) for downtime healing.
- The artificer Repair Light Damage infusion.
- Divine healing in a pinch.
- Infernal Healing as a last resort (effective but would probably result in the party killing or banishing my character).

That's less than ideal since it's relying almost entirely on our artificer.

Low level, RAW solutions are preferred but all are welcome. Both Pathfinder and 3.5 material are allowed.

Comment: As you point out in your question, Repair Light Damage (and the moderate, heavy and critical versions later) are options, and they are as good as healing normal characters, except for who can cast it. Is your question about how to get more healing than a normal character could get? Or is it how to get the healing coming from a Cleric? Or is it how to match the heals/round of heal at higher levels?

Comment: @Scott All off the above. It's deliberately broad to get as many options as possible (my last question was too narrow). Our Warforged isn't getting enough healing as is and we need to increase it. If you undelete your answer, I will give it an upvote. I was not aware that Repair Light damage was available to wizards, so that's an additional option.

Comment: To the D&D 3.5e tag on this question: Do you mean to indicate that 3.5e material is allowed in addition to Pathfinder material? If so, you should state that in your question.

Comment: @JonathanHobbs Yes, both 3.5 and Pathfinder material is allowed (with approval). I will edit the question, thank you!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The repair light/moderate/heavy/critical damage spells from the Eberron books?

Will work as cure light/moderate/heavy/critical wounds.

Sor/wiz, artificer and spellthief only. A cleric can get access to some of these by choosing the Warforged domain.

Also, Total Repair (artificer 6 and warforged domain 8) is the equivalent of heal, and should keep you going for a long time.

Comment: Even if your wizard doesn't want to turn into a cleric, 1st level wands are cheap and easily purchasable in Eberron, and 750 gp for 50 charges of healing isn't a bad purchase. Heck, the Warforged can buy it and give it to the wizard.

When I was playing Living Greyhawk (Convention play, so new party each session) each player had typically had their own, and the cleric won't up with 6+ happy sticks and coloured string on them... some CLW, some Lesser Vigor, I even had some Faith Healing ones, though I never used those.

Answer (score 8):

As a Warforged is treated as a construct creature, the spell **[Make Whole](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/spells/makeWhole.html#_make-whole)** will provide between 3d6 to 5d6 of healing per 2nd level spell slot and is on the Wizard/Sorcerer Cleric spell lists.

Answer (score 5):

Another thing to remember unless it has been changed for Warforged in Pathfinder, they should be able to benefit from potions. While potions of *cure _ wounds* are more traditional, there is no reason potions or oils of *repair _ damage* cannot be created. Likewise, wands of *repair _ damage* can also be created, which would let characters with Use Magic Device help heal a damaged warforge.

Additionally don't forget the druid *goodberry* spell and the various *vigor* spells. In fact, check with your DM on how *vigor* will work on warforged. The warforged living construct traits specifies that spells from the Conjuration (Healing) subschool that 'cure hit point damage or ability damage' only have half effect. However the *vigor* spells don't cure hit point damage, but rather grant varying levels and durations of fast healing. You may be able to talk your DM into allowing the *vigor* spells full effect on warforged.