# Is there any problem with Android PCs healing via the Make Whole spell?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, healing

I'm about to start running the Iron Gods campaign for some friends, and the thought occurred to me: players who choose to play as an Android are constructs, and thus the *Make Whole* spell would work on them, in addition to other standard healing spells. Is it abusable for construct PCs to have access to this extra healing option?

I can't think of a way myself, but this is my first time really delving into the rules as DM.

Comment: [Related] [How can we compensate for a Warforged's lack of healing?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/45338/how-can-we-compensate-for-a-warforgeds-lack-of-healing)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not really "abusable". The spellcaster casting "Make Whole" still must have it prepared and/or it takes up one of their spells for that day so its use is still limited by the power of the spellcaster casting it.

It is more powerful, as a second level spell, because it can cure a max of 30(5D6 at level 5) vs. Cure Moderate Wounds which can cure a max of 26(2d8+10 at level 10). I don't think that really qualifies as "abusable" since it still takes up a Level 2 spell known slot and a spell used per day.

It's more like a racial trait. Constructs can be "Made Whole" instead of just having wounds "Cured".

Comment: Yeah, I see your point. If the entire party were androids, it may make encounters easier for the players (since they may be more likely to full heal an injury they incur), but this can be remedied by increasing the difficulty of encounters, introducing more status effects that can't be removed so easily, or even going so far as to claim something to the effect of "androids are really complicated. Make whole proves less effective against their advanced circuitry", but these may end up not being necessary anyway. Will depend on how the players do things.

Comment: @Barillas Using 2nd level spell slots for healing between encounters is highly suboptimal, especially when it's specifically prepared. A wand of *cure light wounds* heals 0.37 hp/gp, and is the usual go-to way to heal up, unless your PCs have no qualms with and time for using *infernal healing* instead (0.67 hp/gp).

Comment: Agreed, @MrLemon. If they're burning up major spell slots out of combat, that seems sub-optimal. I was more concerned about in-combat applications, and should have noted it as such in my original question.